# ggplot: bar positions shifted right with geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a short horizontal line to a bar plot.  The left edge of the line begins at the y-axis, and the right edge extends into the plotting surface.  This line denotes the mean value for the y-axis variable.  I'm using `geom_segment()` to add the line, but this shifts the positions of the bars to the right.
How can I add the line without moving the position of the bars?

Also, why does this happen?  It almost seems like `geom_segment()` occupies a certain area of the rendering surface, rather than printing on top of the existing graph.

Sample data frame:

```
df
      x        y
1 FALSE 13.02041
2  TRUE 14.37956
```

Without `geom_segment()`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: without line]

With `geom_segment()`:

```
avg.y <- 14.27065
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=.1, y=avg.y, yend=avg.y))
```

[image: with line]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bar plot, the bars are (implicitly) centered at 1 and 2 and extend about +/- 0.45 in either direction. So, you can change the x-range of the segment to get it positioned where you want it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.5, xend=2.5, y=avg.y, yend=avg.y), colour="red") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

In response to your comment, let's look at the underlying structure of your original plot, using `ggplot_build`. Now let's look at the `data` element of `pb`. Note in the first data frame, which is the internal plot data for the bars, that the bars are positioned at x=1 and x=2. `xmin` and `xmax` show the extent of the bar widths. The second data frame is the internal segment positioning. The segment is positioned from x=0 to x=0.1. So there's nothing between 0.1 (the right edge of the segment) and 0.45 (the left edge of the `FALSE` bar), and this can be seen in the second plot you posted in your question.

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=0.1, y=avg.y, yend=avg.y))

pb = ggplot_build(p)
pb$data
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>   x        y PANEL group ymin     ymax xmin xmax colour   fill size linetype alpha
> 1 1 13.02040     1     1    0 13.02040 0.55 1.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
> 2 2 14.37956     1     2    0 14.37956 1.55 2.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
>
> [[2]]
>   x xend        y     yend PANEL group colour size linetype alpha
> 1 0  0.1 14.27065 14.27065     1    -1    red  0.5        1    NA
> 2 0  0.1 14.27065 14.27065     1    -1    red  0.5        1    NA
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I do have the segment where I want it, starting at `x=0`, and extending to `x=0.1`.  But I don't seem to be able to put it there without moving the bars.  Are you saying that I need to move the position of the segment more to the center if I want the bars to stay put?  How does the implicit positioning of the bars impact the addition of a new plot element?  I think I'm still not really understanding the relationship there.

Comment: The bars are not moving. The left bar is centered at 1 and extends from about 0.55 to 1.45 and the left edge of the plot is at about x=0.5. When you add a segment that extends from x=0 to x=0.1, ggplot expands the x axis to start at around x=-0.1, so there is now empty space between the left edge of the plot and the first bar.

Comment: The `ggplot_build` helped me to see what you're getting at.  Thank you!